# How do I reach an object that created from another class's constructor

Tags: java, class, object, constructor, tostring

I tried to create trip object in Bus class constructor but I can't reach it from main class.

I thought I stored trip object in Trip class but console said it can't find the symbol, then I thought it stored at Bus class but it didn't work either

Main class

```
public class Interface
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {       
        Bus bus1 = new Bus(1);
        Trip.trip1.toString();
    }
}
```

Bus class

```
public class Bus
{
    private int tripNumber;
    private String model;
    private String type;
    private int age;
    private int capacity;
    private int remainingCapacity;
    private boolean[][] seats;
    
    public Bus(int tripNumber)
    {
        this.tripNumber = tripNumber;
        
        if (tripNumber==1)
        {
            this.model = "Setra";
            this.type = "2+2";
            this.age = 8;
            this.capacity = 40;
            this.remainingCapacity = 23;
            
            Trip trip1 = new Trip(this, tripNumber);
        }
    }
    public String toString()
    {
        return ("\n\tBus Information:\n\t\tBus: " + this.model + "\n\t\tType: " + this.type + "\n\t\tAge: " + this.age + "\n\t\tCapacity" + this.capacity + "\n\t\tRemainingCapacity" + this.remainingCapacity);
    }
}
```

Trip class

```
public class Trip
{
    private int tripNumber;
    private String date;
    private String origin;
    private String destination;
    private String departureTime;
    private String arrivalTime;
    private Bus assignedBus;
    
    public Trip(Bus bus, int tripNumber)
    {
        if (tripNumber==1)
        {
            this.tripNumber = 1;
            this.assignedBus = bus;
            this.date = "27/11/2022";
            this.origin = "Ankara";
            this.destination = "Istanbul";
            this.departureTime = "00:15";
            this.arrivalTime = "06:30";
        }
    }
    
    public String toString()
    {
        return tripNumber + ") Trip Information: \n\tDate: " + this.date + "\n\tFrom: " + this.origin + " to " + this.destination + "\n\tTrip time: " + this.departureTime + " to " + this.arrivalTime + this.assignedBus.toString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of problems in the code.

**Bus.java**

You have declared the `trip1` variable as a local variable that only exists within the constructor, and hence it is not available and cannot be referenced elsewhere. Make it a class variable to make it available to the instances of your class.

**Interface.java**

You are trying to access the `trip1` variable at the class level whereas you should access it on the instance of the *Bus* class (something like `bus1.trip1.toString()` it is better to create a getter for this purpose). **NOTE**: You will need to fix the first issue for this to work.

See the working code here - https://ideone.com/ej8IGD (note that the main class name has changed as required by the platform)

While this will work - I would strongly suggest you to restructure the code a bit to handle cases like handling more than one trip (hint: use a List/Array)